# Sorting MySQL fields in different order on different sites

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table called "Fruits" and in that table I have a row called "Fruit" which has six entries: Apple, Banana, Kiwi, Orange, Peach, Tangerine.

I have four websites that want to sort the result of SELECT * FROM `Fruits` in different ways, but there is no pattern to them. **They're not random**, since each site will decide a different way to sort them. For example, one site might be "Kiwi, Apple, Banana, Tangerine, Orange, Peach" and the next might be, "Banana, Kiwi, Apple, Peach, Tangerine, Orange."

Can these be sorted in MySQL like this, bearing in mind that future items might be added and need to be sorted again arbitrarily at the whim of each site? Or is there a way to sort these results in PHP after they have been pulled?

Comment: No, they are not random. Each site wants a specified order that will be different to the other sites.

Comment: i don't see any pattern in you question ! you only specified 2 order examples

Comment: I think you can do with mysql using ORDER BY FIELD() given the fact that u know the sort order for each site. Check the doc here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: Kinda depends ... I've previously used a `site` table in the database to store config options for different sites running on the same system. You could then have a table like `fruit_to_site` holding the `fruit.id`, `site.id` and a `sort_order` index - then you can sort your fruits by site. Or, if the sites are running on different code, but from the same database, you could do the sort at the application level.

Comment: @CD001 solution seems feasible

Comment: Up_One, exactly, that's the point. The developer doesn't know the order. The CMS user will decide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this ended up working the best here:

```
    SELECT `fruit` 
    FROM (`Fruit`) 
    ORDER BY FIELD(`fruit`, 'Tangerine','Banana','Apple', 'Orange', 'Peach', 'Kiwi') ASC
```

As raina77ow suggested, I created a sort map to hold the values I want to inject into the query. That gets held as a config value we can switch for each site. Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is setting up so-called 'sorting maps' - strings of fruit names, having the items in the exact order you want to them to be shown. Then you'll be able to use this array with [**FIND_IN_SET**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) MySQL function:

```
$sortMap = 'Kiwi,Apple,Banana,Tangerine,Orange,Peach';

$query = >>>QUERY
   SELECT fruit_id, fruit_name
     FROM fruits
 ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(fruit_name, '$sortMap');
QUERY;

// do something with the query
```

To change the ordering, just set the `$sortMap` on per-site basis.

Comment: I like this idea ... assuming you can assign the `$sortMap` on a per-site basis in the application. I'd never considered using `FIND_IN_SET` for sorting before.

Comment: Yeah, actually this looks like it will work well with our site_config options. Then I can run the same query on all sites and just have to update the config file. Cheers, I'll try it.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

```
 SELECT * FROM Fruits ORDER BY rand()
```

- this will give you a random result set order !

Comment: Please read the question again. The OP has said **They're not random**.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to assign some sort of site order identifier to each value, or at least logically group them with a fruit_type field. Otherwise you can use

```
SELECT ... IF(fruit = 'apple',1,0) as fruit_apple ... ORDER BY ... fruit_apple
```

It's an extremely inelegant solution.

Have you considered normalising the tables, moving the apples & ordering to a separate table and then joining them on request?

Comment: In reality they are offices which each have their own website. There are 12 offices in the "office" table which contains all their info. They will always be displayed with the "self" office on top, and after that the order is arbitrary (I pushed for alphabetical, but this won't work). So I suppose a table called "ordering" with "office_id" as a foreign key will work.

Comment: If you have control over the database you could store the information as json meta data, otherwise you're probably looking at something like an EAV or 4 column table with references to foreign keys for the primary office, other offices and the order.

Comment: Not sure why my answer was down voted care to give a reason why?

Answer (score -2):

retrieve values by using this
ORDER BY rand();

Comment: 'No, they are not random. Each site wants a specified order that will be different to the other sites' Who the hell is upvoting this without reading the question?